# SSH configurations per environemnt based on active network connection

Tags: ssh, networking, configuration

I'm using my laptop and SSH to connect to private-IP-only machines in different networks/environments belonging to different clients. So `192.168.1.5` in one network is different from host `192.168.1.5` in other network. I'd like to apply SSH configuration (`Host` stanzas in `~/.ssh/config`) to these different hosts but that can't work as I can only specify configuration per IP.

How do you cope with this?

FYI I'm using NetworkManager to connect to networks (though I don't have much hope it can be of any help here).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `host` and `hostname` in your `.ssh/config` file:

```
host mySpot1
hostname 192.168.1.5
forwardagent yes

host mySpot2
hostname 192.168.1.5
forwardagent no
```

From the man page for `ssh_config`:

> HostName
>
> Specifies the real host name to log into.  This can be used to specify nicknames or abbreviations for hosts.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem. I know how to refer to different hostnames/IPs by SSH aliases. When I'm in the network where `mySpot2` is, connecting to `mySpot1` will still try to connect to invalid IP.

Comment: I guess I don't understand you problem then. Using the alias you can connect to different hosts using different parameters, like a different key. What parameters are you using that are different? You can use an agent to hold different keys and it will try multiple (5 I think?). Can you clarify what you need or what's not working?